# WPF binding: Bind to parent of DataContext

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

OK. It's WPF and I'm trying to bind my window to my ViewModel. The VM looks like this:

```
public class VM
{
    public SalesRecord SR {get; set;} 
    public List<string> AllSalesTypes {get; set;}
}

public class SalesRecord
{
    public int ID {get; set;} 
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
}
```

Here's my XAML:

```
...
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ID, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Date, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllSalesTypes}" Text="{Binding Path=SalesType, Mode=TwoWay}" />
...
```

I'm setting the data context to a `VM` object at runtime like this:

```
this.DataContext = _vm.SR;
```

Now the binding expressions work for all my `TextBoxes` that are point to the properties of `SR` object (e.g. `ID` and `Date`), but the `ComboBox` that needs to show the list of all SalesTypes does not work, obviously because `AllSalesTypes` is a member of the `VM` class.

My questions is: Is there a way to write a binding expression that looks into the parent of the current `DataContext` instead of itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any way you can use Binding to get the Parent of the DataContext.
Just like if you have a class `A` which has a property named `MyProperty` and you write:

```
 object o = MyAInstance.MyProperty;
```

You have no way to find `MyAInstance` from your instance of `o`.

Your options are either using: `this.DataContext = _vm` and accessing the properties like this:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding SR.ID}" />
```

OR add a `Parent` property to `SalesRecord` and manually set it to point to the VM, then something like this will work:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding ID}" />
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Parent.AllSalesTypes}" />
```

Comment: This is the answer I had already written, but you have been faster. But... When you set DataContext to VM and use Text="{Binding SR.ID}" Only OneWay binding works when you change some properties of SR PropertyChanged event is not raised. You have to raise it if you want to propagate those changes to the TextBox's Text property. But yeah :) take my upvote :)

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix Correct, just like any other class in which you want to see the changes in the UI - SalesRecord should also implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Yes... or you can RaisePropertyChanged("SR") in VM... also works :) And SalesRecord doesn't have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Thanks guys. This appears to be the only option. I was thinking on the lines of RelativeSource kind of thing, but it looks like those options are more about the controls rather than the data source. I guess I'll settle with SR.ID stuff for now.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off making the model (data context) for your view the view model (hence the name) and changing your text box bindings to:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SR.ID}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SR.Date}" />
```

I would also strongly recommend using an MVVM framework if you're using MVVM. You should really be implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your view model types - MVVM frameworks provide an implementation of this.

Comment: I'm a WPF newbie. Have spent years and years doing that "Button1_Click" kind of programming, first in VB and then in .NET WinForms. It has only been a few weeks that I have started WPF + MVVM + Unity and that too on a real-world project. So you can imagine that the curve is already steep for me. Do you think an MVVM framework is going to make learning easier for me? If yes, which framework do you suggest?

Comment: Yes an MVVM framework will make life a lot easier for you, particularly as your app gets more complex. I would recommend Caliburn.Micro. MVVM Light is also very popular, but I would have a look at using one of them sooner rather than later.